# Batch Exclamation Mark Variable

Tags: python, windows, shell, batch-file, cmd

I'm converting a Batch script to Python. I got stuck here:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F %%x in ('dir /B/D %OPATH%') do (
    set "FILENAME=!FILENAME! %%x"
)
```

I don't understand what

```
set "FILENAME=!FILENAME! %%x"
```

does.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, `%var%` retrieves the value of `var`.

Within a `code block` (a parenthesised series of lines), `%var%` will be replaced by the value of `var` when the statement invoking the block (a `for` or an `if`) was encountered, not the value of `var` as it varies due to the operation of the block (the `run-time` value).

When `delayedexpansion` is invoked, `%var%` still returns the original, `parse-time` value, but `!var!` returns the the `run-time` value, so in this case, `filename` has each value of `%%x` appended to it as the loop proceeds. (Caution : there is a limit of ~8180 characters in a batch variable [actually, 8191-length of variablename])

Answer (score 2):

The for loop concatenates all found dir entries to one string.

BTW the /B of dir overrides the /D, so it can be omitted.

Also the default for /f options `"tokens=1 delims= "` will truncate file names with spaces.

Magoo explained the other issues fine.

Answer (score 1):

The batch script is producing a space separated list of the OPATH directory file names. It is easy enough to use Python `glob` to get the same thing as a list.

```
import os
import glob
dlist = glob.glob(os.environ['OPATH'] + os.sep + '*')
```

This will produce a list of file names. Directory names will have an os.sep at the end of them. This might be easier for your Python code to handle than a single string with space separators.

If you must have a space delimited string they can easily be joined.

```
dstring = ' '.join(dlist)
```